# encode a value to UTF 32

Tags: utf, utf-32

I am trying to test my Unicode 32 decoder program I had to write for a class at school. I am looking for a solution which will accurately write UTF 32 bytes to a file so I can attempt to decode them.

I've been trying to develop a way to test it without having to program a Unicode to UTF32 encoder (which means I would have to then test THAT as well). I have been using a program I found online called editpad (https://www.editpadlite.com/) which would allow me to encode in utf32.. which I could then test my program on.

However, I would try encoding U+2A580 (unicode codepoint) in that program, and  then use the terminal command in linux

```
od -tx1 file.txt
```

to view it, and would see the result as:

```
00 00 fe ff 00 00 d8 69 00 00 dd 80
```

Which with the exception of the BOM made no sense to me. Am I just understanding UTF32 incorrectly? Or is there an error.. I would expect the UTF32 value to be something like 02 a5 80

EDIT: my operating system is Linux, Fedora specifically. Fedora Release 24

Comment: Could you edit your operating system into the Question?

Comment: This should be a programming problem given you're asking on Stack Overflow, so the code in your program that does the conversion is relevant and yet omitted.

Comment: @tadman figured it was programming related.. my code in this case, does not matter as I am asking about how can I better test it.

Comment: @Paulb absolutely. edited it.. should have included it the first time. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that Unicode codepoint `U+2A580` is encoded as the following byte sequence in UTF-32BE:

`00 02 A5 80`

What you are actually seeing happen is the codepoint being encoded in UTF-16 first, and then the two UTF-16 surrogate code units (0xD869, 0xDD80) are being individually encoded in UTF-32BE.

Another indication of this happening is the first byte sequence:

`00 00 FE FF`

While that *is* the UTF-32BE BOM, it is **also** the UTF-16BE BOM encoded in UTF-32BE.

So, either:

- EditPad is erroneously doing a double-encode.
- EditPad is saving to UTF-16 despite you telling it to save to UTF-32, and then your `od` output is misrepresenting the UTF-16 input as UTF-32.